# Moving spotlight (or object) between 2 coordinates (image included)

Tags: 3d

Given the origin position and direction for a spotlight.
How can I smoothly move a spotlight between two 3D coordinates?
Please use the picture below so I can easily comprehend this. I would like to move the direction of the spotlight from point A to B, for example.
**All values/vectors are in 3D.**

EDIT: 
How should I properly do this, if given only current **position** and **unit direction** of spotlight?
[image]

Comment: So you need a vector pointing at the positions or an angle of the heading?

Comment: I need whatever will help, whether it be more vectors or angles.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the same problem as making a camera track to follow an object moving between two points.  Might want to investigate it from that perspective (heh).

Comment: "direction for a pointlight" - do you mean direction for a spot light? Point lights don't generally have a direction as they are omni-directional.

Comment: @user1118321 Yes, spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

Your spotlight direction should be of unit length, therefore, you can perform interpolation.

Method A - Linear:

Take the unit direction of spotlight to point A, then the direction of the light to point B. Then decide how quickly you want to rotate the light. Let's say over 5 seconds.
unit(DirB - DirA)/5 = your rotPerS.

Then: lightDir+=rotPerS * deltaTime, or lightDir-=rotDir * deltaTime to rotate back.

Method B - Spherical:

Compute the axis you wish to rotate the direction of the light on. Get the dot product of DirA and DirB. This is the cosine of the angle between them, on that axis. To compute the axis, perform a cross product of DirA and DirB.

Decide on your rotation speed again. You now have the rotation angle per second, and the axis upon which you must rotate, and how long it will take to rotate.

Then you can use a quaternion to rotate the direction of the light based on angle/axis, by multiplying the direction vector by the quaternion.

Like so:

axis = cross(dirA,DirB);

angle = dot(DirA,DirB);

anglePerSec = angle/Duration; (radians)

rotateQ = Quaternion(anglePerSec * deltaTime,axis);

lightDir = rotateQ * lightDir;

Answer (score 1):

If you use Unity 3D
Create an empty object and make it move from A to B any way you want, you can use a "lerp" for this:

```
float smooth = 0
void Update () {
         smooth += (Time.deltatime) * speed;
         transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (A.position, B.position, smooth);
     }
```

The "smooth" values they serve range from 0 to 1, less than zero takes it as zero, greater than 1 takes it as 1.

Then make the "spotlight" look at your moving object.

```
public class ExampleClass: MonoBehaviour
{
     public Transform target;

     void Update ()
     {
         // Rotate the spotlight every frame so it keeps looking at the target
         transform.LookAt (target);
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Unity, but I was thinking of doing something like this. For the game I'm using, I can create a small object that's invisible and has no collision. And then point the light at the object, as you mentioned. I will definitely further consider this. Thanks.